# On which of the websites of Stack Exchange one can ask about career options and expert advice from software professionals?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a software developer and have started my career recently. I want to decide how to steer my career and to get some advice from experience people in this field.

I looked through the list of all websites under Stack Exchange and could only think of Programmers.SE as my best option. But I am not so sure after reading about it in the 'about' page.

Where I can ask my question without being down voted by other members? If there isn't any such group, I suggest that it be included in Stack Exchange.

Comment: You're right, Programmers is not a good place for such questions. Glad to see that the About page is not in vain.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: related: [Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216589/165773)

Answer (score 9):

Although career questions are generally off-topic on Programmers (thank you for reading our About page and our Help Center pages), we do have a [chat room for Programmers called The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). The room tends to be most active during the day in the US (from about 9am - 9pm Eastern, I believe), but there are people who do pop in from time to time. Most of the people there are in various roles as professionals in various types of software development roles. The Workplace also has [its own chat room, The Water Cooler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), but I'm not there and active as much as I am in the Programmers chat.

Because you're looking for advice, I'd highly recommend a chat room. If you're looking for advice and extended discussion, that's the place to go on the SE network. Otherwise, you're probably going to want to look at various places off the network. I've had good luck with Reddit before, but I'm sure there are other places as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to ask my question in a chat because there I will have only a limited audience who would be on-line at that moment. Your stackoverflow also says somewhere that this is strictly not a career guidance website... which means a lot of people would have asked such questions. So Stack exchange should think of opening this branch soon as I can see you also have a group for bicycles. Career guidance I think is a bit more important than that which deserves to have a separate website instead of a chat..

Comment: @MKSingh On Stack Exchange, chat is persistent. That is, old messages are searchable. In addition, when a person logs on, they can see old messages from before they signed on. It's not like IRC. In addition, it's a good place to go to help formulate your question - people who are familiar with the site can help you make a question that won't get closed but will still get you the answers you need. Finally, Stack Exchange sites are for Q&A, not any kind of extended discussion, suggestions, or advice, so a site like you're proposing would probably never open.

Comment: I read a few other links in the comments on my question too and felt and understood that such questions are actually beneficial to the person asking the question and not those answering, but may help someone with a similar query. So I understand somewhat why such a site won't open.